# SignalR Core track connected users

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 SignalR Hub.

I'd like to track the connected users in a multi-threaded environment.

According to Microsoft, Hubs are transient so one shouldn't store any state on it.

Below is my Hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private static bool _isLocked;
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    // I want to remove this state property
    private static readonly List<OnlineUser> _users = new List<OnlineUser>();

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        if (!_isLocked)
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (!_isLocked)
                {
                    _isLocked = true;

                    _users.Add(new Online User
                    {
                        ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
                        UserName = ""
                    });

                    _isLocked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried the below static class which would be referenced in the Hub:

```
public static class OnlineUsers
{
    private static List<OnlineUser> Users = new List<OnlineUser>();
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // code omitted for brevity
        OnlineUsers.Users.Add(new OnlineUser
        {
            ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
            UserName = ""
        });
    }
}
```

I've also found examples where a concurrent dictionary can be used, but this would again be storing state on the Hub:
`private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, OnlineUser> _users;`

What is the recommended way to do this as I don't see any guidelines in Microsoft's own documentation other than you need to track this yourself.

Comment: Using static ConcurrentDictionary is not really storing a state in the hub. You just need to handle concurrency issues (which I can see you already used a lock)
I would suggest using SlimSemaphore instead of lock.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `HubConnectionContext.Items` Property in the dotnet library

```
// Gets a key/value collection that can be used to share data within the scope of this connection.

public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object,object> Items { get; }
```

I also read you can use a database or even an in memory database.

The way I am going to do this is by using DI to register a Singleton service that can live for the whole life-cycle of my application. This way I can scale it to hold any kind of state I need. I think that would give you the flexibility you are looking for without breaching best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using a static concurrent dictionary in a separate static class that is referenced by the Hub.